# I am trying to upload multiple images in laravel and facing issues as the same image is uploaded each time?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

The problem is that my loop only running and uploading the same first pic each time rather than uploading each other in a row one after one!

Here is my code of the form

```
{!! Form::file('photos[]', ['roles' => 'form', 'class' => 'form-control-file','multiple' => true]) !!}
```

Here is my code of the controller

```
            $files=$request->file('photos');
            foreach ($files as $file) {   
            $insert = new Images;
            $insert->youth_fashion_images_category = $request->selectproduct; 
            $destinationPath = 'uploads/products';
            $imageName = 'uploads/products/'.time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
                $insert->Save();
                $uid = $insert->id;
             $file->move($destinationPath,$imageName);
             $image = array(
                'youth_fashion_images_img' => $imageName
            );
             Images::where('youth_fashion_images_id',$uid)->update($image);    
           }


             return redirect('adminpanel/viewimages');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
if($request->hasfile('photos'))
         {    
            foreach($request->file('photos') as $image)
            {                                    
                $destinationPath = 'uploads/products';
                $imageName = 'uploads/products/'.time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
                $image->move($destinationPath,$imageName);                    

                $insert = new Images;
                $insert->youth_fashion_images_category = $request->selectproduct; 
                $insert->youth_fashion_images_img = $imageName;                 
                $insert->Save();                  
            }
         }
```

Comment: it doesn't makes any difference!

Answer (score 0):

You should try this code.

```
if($request->hasfile('photos')) {

    foreach($request->file('photos') as $image)
    {
        $destinationPath = 'uploads/products';
        $name = 'uploads/products/'.time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalName();
        $image->move($destinationPath, $name);  
        $data[] = $name;  
    }
}

$insert= new Images;
$insert->youth_fashion_images_img = json_encode($data);

$insert->save();
```

**json_encode to insert the multiple image names in one row.**
So add $name in array `$data[] = $name;`.
I hope this will helps.

Comment: i am not trying  to enter multiple images in same row i want to have each image in its own row in table!